# Why does the Terminal minimize when initiated in Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: unity, command-line, gnome-terminal, steam, 15.04

After installing Ubuntu 15.04 update Steam quit working.
So I tried to remove Steam installer and reinstall it; along with the installation I received the message:

Steam, Steamdeps are run in a Terminal.

So I opened the 'Terminal' (gnome-terminal) and it immediately minimized to the upper left corner of the screen. Dragging the edges of it would only work occasionally and limited the size of the terminal to about 32 characters wide x 4 characters long before jumping back to a 2x2 character size square.

As a precaution I took screen shots of the installation information in the Ubuntu software center and the desktop with Terminal minimized.

After struggling with it I finally got it to open enough to enter >Steam< and got:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.04 64-bit
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1428965940)
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I also tried >steamdeps< and got:

```
Usage: /usr/bin/steamdeps dependencies.txt
```

I believe I am WAY out of my league here and am beginning to regret my selecting to upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04.

Are there any answers out there? And does anyone have suggestions for a novice Ubuntu usr like me?